# The effect of position in comparing an object with a null reference

Tags: java, javascript

I would like to know the difference(w.r.t code size and/or performance) of the following snippets:

```
if(null == someObject.getSomeProperty()){
                ...
}
```

vs

```
if(someObject.getSomeProperty() == null ){
                ...
}
```

Comment: Obviously you know if the `someObject` itself is null, both lines will throw an NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion performance and generated bytecode size should be the same. The first pointed style ( `null == value`) comes from C/C++ where anything different from 0 was considered **true** while something equal to 0 was **false**. To avoid an issue it is approached in this way: null == value, then you made sure that this is a condition.

As java has a [boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.5) type, it is useless to approach a condition this way, more it is considered a bad practice. It is referred to as [Yoda Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

A sole reason where this approach should be used when verified against a literal value:

```
if("someValue".equals(input)) {
   // do something
}

if (BigDecimal.ONE.equals(input)) {
  // do something
}
```

writing the code in the natural way would throw a [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) exception if the input is **null** hence the condition should be written more defensive like:

```
if (input != null && input.equals("someValue")) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in the performance. Furthermore in modern languages that shouldn't be any of your concern since the compiler would do the optimization for you.

The only reason for writing these so-called "yoda conditions" (having the compare statement in the 'wrong' order) is comparing specific values to values that might be null when using `equals`, example:

```
if("blue".equals(sky.getColor())){
  //...
}
```

because if you wanted to write it the intuitive way, you'd have to perfom a manual null check:

```
if(sky.getColor() != null && sky.getColor().equals("blue")){
  //...
}
```